# Irreducible representations of product of two algebras, $A \times B$

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

I am taking the cartesian product here. I have been playing around and came up with:

> Let $A,B$ be two f.d. semisimple $k$-algebra. We may define a $k$-algebra $A\times B$. Suppose the class of irreducible reps. of $A$, $B$ are $\{V_i \} , \{W_j \}$ respectively.
>
> **Claim:** The class of irreducible representations (upto isomorphism) of $A \times B$ consists of $V_i \times \{0 \}$ and $\{0 \} \times W_j$.

*My proof: (general idea)*

> *Lemma:* Let $M$ be irreducible $A$-module. Then $M$ appears as a composition factor of a composition series of ${_A}A$.
>
> (Using semisimplicity) $A \cong \bigoplus n_i V_i, B \cong \bigoplus m_jW_j$ as $A$-modules, $B$-modules. $n_i, m_j$ are multiplicites. Then $A \times B \cong \bigoplus n_i V_i \times \bigoplus m_j W_j $ as $A \times B$-modules.  We thus obtain a composition series for $A \times B$ as $A \times B$-module with composition factors as listed.

Is this correct?
Note: I am not sure if finite dimnesional is required.

Comment: Why are you using semisimplicity? "Composition series" is the word you need.

Comment: Semisimplicity so $A$ can be written as a direct sum of simple submodules.

Comment: No need for that. Take your composition series for $A$ and $B$, and use them to build one for $A \times B$.